# QGIS: can I somehow display a virtual raster of 7000 zipped GeoTiffs?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, vrt

I've built a virtual raster of 7000 zipped geotiffs (each about 3600x2400 px). The GeoTIFFs have overviews.

I've tried to open it with QGIS desktop application (via Add Raster Layer).

Alas, QGIS hung up.

Can I somehow show such a layer? Maybe I should split it to tiles?

Comment: Your geotiffs should have internal compression so zipping them doesn't help.